# Qt Creator doesn't autohide/-show the debug panes

Tags: user-interface, debugging, qt-creator, panes

I launched my app in the Qt Creator debugger, then closed the app. The debug panes didn't hide automatically. Then I waited a bit until the status bar said "Debugger finished." but even then they did not hide automatically.

My window looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Maybe this is a missing feature and I need to close them myself? **Any ideas?**

**Edit:** Now I see that even closing them manually is not a full solution, as:

- Even when I close the 3 panes, something remains: the horizontal dark bar (the one that says "Debugger" in its left part)
- When I relaunch the debugger, the 3 debug panes don't get auto-shown.

Hmm, all this is making me feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong... this is basic stuff I'm asking about.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I figured it out. I just needed to switch from "Debug mode" to "Edit mode" via the leftmost dark vertical button bar. That hides the debug panes and bars. And vice versa - switching to the "Debug mode" button shows the debug stuff.

Confusing when I'm used to Visual Studio, but workable I guess.

Comment: I just ran into this myself; I concur about the confusion. Not sure why the "Debug mode" is valid when no debugger is running.